# vs code polymer nodejs application - does not load

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I have a polymer application on nodejs. I am able to launch from vscode, but when I visit the site in the browser, it gives me

`Cannot GET /`

The browser console prints

```
jquery.min.js:562 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-33YGiROm4Pzv0xXIPo82M0Dt2zrdnP4IgbJq1WeAtf8='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:562
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:605
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2462
```

When I run `npm start` from the terminal, the site loads fine. I have the chrome extension installed in vscode.

My launch.json entry:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "xxxx-xxx",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/xxxx-xxx/server.js",
  "env": {"PORT":"6015"}
}
```

I have tried running on different browsers just to ensure this is not an extension in the browser and I get the same results in all browsers. No idea why this works from the terminal, but not from inside vscode :(.

Comment: Is it a single page application? How are you adding references to the polymer elements in HTML files (if used) ? I'd like to know the way you are consuming the polymer elements.

Comment: Thanks @ManojChalode. The project uses bower and <link> to refer to polymer elements. <link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">. I just tried importing the project into netbeans and it works fine. But I want to use vscode !

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the same issue but I faced the same problem while using polymer elements in express application. The way I used polymer components was I added the polymer imports in an HTML file which was referred in the index HTML in the SPA. I then used polymer cli to vulcanize the polymer reference HTML file & thta resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks @ManojChalode, I don't understand why this is vs code issue? It works from netbeans and also if I start the application from terminal. I am now trying to start from terminal and attach from vscode so I can step through code :(.